# Force reload of a module every time in web2py

Tags: web2py, web2py-modules

Many thanks for reading:

I have to following code in a .py file calling a web2py function within the default controller:

Snippet of code in .py running from IDLE - **username** and **password** are imported correctly

```
payload = {'username': username, 'password': password} 
r = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/webappfiletransfer/default/server_file_list_create.json/x/y/z', params=payload)
```

In web2py I have the following code to
1:Accept the username and password and
2:Compare them with saved in web2py username and password variables

The file containing **username** and **password** is **parameters.py** stored in **myappfilefolder/modules/parameters.py**  within the web2py environment

---

**EDIT**: It seems that after a complete system restart there is the need to put parameters.py in web2py/site-packages as well, as I have found in several SO answers and regardless the fact that

> Once a module "mymodule.py" is placed into an app "modules/" folder, it can be imported from anywhere inside a web2py application (without need to alter sys.path with):import mymodule

as the documentation states. Obviously I am missing something

---

parameters.py is

> username="testacc"
>   password="1234"

Web2py Code is:

```
from gluon.custom_import import track_changes
track_changes(True)

import parameters

usrname = request.vars['username'] 
passwd =  request.vars['password']

if (usrname==parameters.username and passwd==parameters.password):
```

**Problem**: Although I am using

```
from gluon.custom_import import track_changes
track_changes(True)
```

which as I have understood forces a reload of the modules imported, the following behaviour is taking place:

In the first call from IDLE and if parameters are wrong in parameters.py  I have the *unauthorized* message I have put to print, since  the parameters are wrong.

Editing the file **parameters.py** with the correct **username/password** , I have a correct validation and a succesful return from web2py.

Editing again the file parameters.py and entering wrong credentials DOES NOT causes
an error again and web2py returns corretly although wrong credentials are supplied. All subsequent calls return a successful result regardless the credentials.

**Is there something I miss from using**

```
 from gluon.custom_import import track_changes
track_changes(True)
```

or something else I should consider in order to trigger a wrong validation again without closing first web2py.